# Is "yum update" safe?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, yum, centos-6

CentOS 6.6

I have a production server and a test server. I just tried "yum update" on the latter and everything looked fine. It took 14 minutes. Before I repeat the operation on my critical server, I would like to get some reassurance.

My main doubt is this: I have many processes running, let's say mysql. What happens when the new image (executable) replaces the old one? Shouldn't the daemon be stopped, replaced and restarted? Should I reboot the system after the update? Is this done automatically by "yum update"?

TIA

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question. Who downclicked and why?

Comment: "What happens when the new image (executable) replaces the old one?" - It won't be replaced if its currently being used.  "Shouldn't the daemon be stopped, replaced and restarted?" - Yes  "Shouldn't the daemon be stopped, replaced and restarted?" - Yes  "Who downclicked and why?" - It does not seem very well researched honestly.  Since voting is anonymous and leaving a comment is optional you likely will never know the actual reason somebody had.  I suggest pouring your energy into improving your question rather then worry about a single downvote.

Comment: " I suggest pouring your energy into improving your question rather then worry about a single downvote." It is not a single downvote. They ALWAYS do this. It could be retaliation against users that complain. How on earth am I supposed to pour energy into a question that seems perfectly reasonable? Should I move it north? east? west? south? Without a compass?

Comment: There are always ways to improve a question. I attempted to give you constructive feedback, if I am burned for doing so, I really won't appreciate it.  You only have one other question, which only has a single vote, not sure I agree your stance "they always do this".

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! My complaint is about the people that seem to have a perverse fixation on putting users down. They are scaring away many potential users.

Comment: Since when were votes about the user and not the quality of the content?  **Stop taking votes personal.**  You should improve this question.  You have a test server, you could in theory, easily answer this question yourself.

Comment: What is your actual question?  Are you asking whether you need to follow a specific procedure to get a proper update (i.e., yum isn't smart enough to do the job right by simply executing it), or is it safe (in what way)?  Are you concerned about corruption?  the system hanging due to conflicts?  failure to actually update?  Are you just looking for instructions on the proper way to use the utility?  Have you looked at the man page or done any research?  Have you come across ambiguous or apparently conflicting information that leaves you with a specific question?